# How do I encode spaces in a YQL url?

Tags: javascript, web-services, yql

I'm trying to get some YQL to work with a webservice. This first snippet works in the YQL console ([http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console))

```
select * from xml where url="http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=Mankato"
```

When I try to add a more complex address using spaces the console gives an error about a Connect Failure:

```
select * from xml where url="http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=Mankato%20MN"
```

The second url works fine if I access it directly: http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=Mankato%20MN

Any ideas on how to encode the second yql query? Eventually I want to call the yql via a url and not just inside the yql console, but I figured the console would be a good place to get it working.

Comment: Have you tried encoding your query string values with `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: It also fails if I use the results of an encodeURIComponent() as the value of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a 302 redirect on the API. Did a curl on `http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=Mankato%20MN` You can try it out `curl -v -L http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=MANKATO%20MN`

Once you do the curl, check the part after the 302. Notice the following:

```
GET /cgi-bin/mapserv?mode=nquery&map=/web/gis/mapserver/districtsxml/demo.map&scale=10000&mapxy=-93.9993996+44.1635775&layer=location&map_location_feature=new&map_location_feature_points=-93.9993996+44.1635775&source=address&address=MANKATO+MN
```

Notice the **address=MANKATO+MN** at the end? For some reason the server where the API is hosted translates the space to a plus sign (I have no clue why).

Anyways, If you issue the query as `select * from xml where url="http://www.gis.leg.mn/mapserver/districtsxml/geocode.php?location=MANKATO%2BMN"` (I have encoded the + in Mankato+MN) then it should work. I verified it myself. Try it out and let me know.

One last note. This doesn't seem like a YQL issue. Check out [YQL request not working when using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125561/yql-request-not-working-when-using-url/10131785#10131785) why I suspect its not a YQL issue.

`